# How to overlap Navbar on Carousel using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want that bootstrap navbar overlap with carousel without making any problem to #test

HTML

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark floating-navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Best Sellers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gift Ideas</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">New Releases</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Today's Deals</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customer Service</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

 <div id="fullCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Image 1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,car" class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Image 2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Image 2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,forest" class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Image 2">
      </div> 

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


 <div id="test">
    <h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim necessitatibus nemo consectetur, ipsa eaque
      similique
      totam voluptas magnam dolore veritatis repudiandae perferendis odio ad at maxime atque asperiores ratione quis!
    </h1>
  </div>
```

In CSS segment I want #test to come after the carousel but it is coming above the carousel and making problem. If I set #full carousel position to relative then #test comes normally below but then it doesn't overlap with navbar, and when I set position to absolute then it overlap perfectly but does not show me text in #test [It can show when I give #test z-index above greater than 2, but it directly comes above the carousel not at the end]

CSS

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .carousel {
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
      height: 80vh;
    }
 
    .carousel-inner img {
      margin: auto;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .navbar {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      margin-top: 10px;
      border-radius: 40px;
  
    }

    #fullCarousel {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
     
      z-index: 1;
    } 
}
```

Mainly getting problem with #full carousel

Comment: Try `.fixed-top` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/?#placement

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the updated CSS:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 80vh;
}

.carousel-inner img {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#fullCarousel {
  position: relative; /* Change to relative */
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3; /* Increase z-index to be above the navbar */
}
```

By setting position: relative for #fullCarousel and increasing its z-index, you should achieve the desired effect where the carousel overlaps with the navbar, and the content in the #test div appears below the carousel.